# How do I stop .htaccess Rewrite redirecting into the html folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cross-domain, directory-structure

I'm hosting on MediaTemple.

I would like **www.rhapsodicmusic.com** to redirect to **www.rhapsodicmusic.co.uk** so that **www.rhapsodicmusic.com/anypageordirectory** will go to **www.rhapsodicmusic.co.uk/anypageordirectory**.

I have the following code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.:]+\.)*rhapsodicmusic\.com\.?(:[0-9]*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rhapsodicmusic.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, this redirect rule sends everything at **rhapsodicmusic.com** to **rhapsodicmusic.co.uk/html** e.g. **rhapsodicmusic.com/test.html** goes to **rhapsodicmusic.co.uk/html/test.html**...

The directory structure is:

domains/
|- rhapsodicmusic.com/
|- |- cgi-bin/
|- |- html/
|- |- .htaccess
|- rhapsodicmusic.co.uk/
|- |- cgi-bin/
|- |- html/
|- |- |- index.html
|- |- |- about.html
|- |- |- etc...

How do I stop it redirecting to that (non-existent) html directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gumbo, what I just got working was this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rhapsodicmusic.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And that seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rhapsodicmusic\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.rhapsodicmusic.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```